# Using "change" or "a change"?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-article

I am wondering which of the following sentences is correct:

(1) - Scientists noticed a recent climate change. (2) - Scientists noticed recent climate change.

I am asking this question because sometimes "change" is used without the indefinite article as in "undergo change".

Thank You!

Comment: _Climate change_ is a gradual process. _A change_  usually refers to a particular thing that has changed, such as _a change in the weather_ (it was sunny and is now wet), or _a change of clothes_ (a different set of garments).

Comment: It depends if you're referring to climate change as a single global phenomenon (mass noun), or you mean a local change in the climate.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! @KateBunting